# Wrong Apple ID for iCloud?

Tags: icloud, apple-id

My initial Apple ID was associated with a now defunct email address. I just updated my AppleID to a real email. I have managed to update it successfully with everything except iCloud on my phone. The App Store, iTunes, everything else on my phone has the correct ID except iCloud. How do I fix this?

Comment: Anything else we can do to answer your question? Did it resolve itself?

Answer (score 6):

Settings -> iCloud (right beneath General). Then scroll down til you see the "Delete Account" button. Should be straight-forward from there.

Comment: Thank you! That was easy! I was afraid that the delete account button would affect more than just iCloud. Thanks!